# C# Linq union multiple properties to one list

Tags: c#, linq

Basically I have an object with 2 different properties, both `int` and I want to get one list with all values from both properties. As of now I have a couple of linq queries to do this for me, but I am wondering if this could be simplified somehow -

```
var componentsWithDynamicApis = result
  .Components
  .Where(c => c.DynamicApiChoicesId.HasValue || 
              c.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.HasValue);

var choiceApis = componentsWithDynamicApis
  .Select(c => c.DynamicApiChoicesId.Value);

var submissionApis = componentsWithDynamicApis
  .Select(c => c.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.Value);

var dynamicApiIds = choiceApis
  .Union(submissionApis)
  .Distinct();
```

Not every component will have both Choices and Submissions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By simplify, I assume you want to combine into fewer statements. You can also simplify in terms of execution by reducing the number of times you iterate the collection (the current code does it 3 times).

One way is to use a generator function (assuming the type of items in your `result.Components` collection is `Component`):

```
IEnumerable<int> GetIds(IEnumerable<Component> components)
{
    foreach (var component in components)
    {
        if (component.DynamicApiChoicesId.HasValue) yield return component.DynamicApiChoicesId.Value;
        if (component.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.HasValue) yield return component.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.Value;
    }
}
```

Another option is to use `SelectMany`. The trick there is to create a temporary enumerable holding the appropriate values of `DynamicApiChoicesId` and `DynamicApiSubmissionsId`. I can't think of a one-liner for this, but here is one option:

```
var dynamicApiIds = result
    .Components
    .SelectMany(c => {
        var temp = new List<int>();
        if (c.DynamicApiChoicesId.HasValue) temp.Add(c.DynamicApiChoicesId.Value);
        if (c.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.HasValue) temp.Add(c.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.Value);
        return temp;
    })
    .Distinct();
```

@Eldar's answer gave me an idea for an improvement on option #2:

```
var dynamicApiIds = result
    .Components
    .SelectMany(c => new[] { c.DynamicApiChoicesId, c.DynamicApiSubmissionsId })
    .Where(c => c.HasValue)
    .Select(c => c.Value)
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: Was just thinking about the generator function! But think the second option fits the build

Comment: @Adjit I forgot `Distinct` on the second one. Just added that.

Comment: that last edit tho...

Comment: I'm voting for this answer because of the third solution.  Sometime you need to be clever enough to see the obvious!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to some of the other answers, but I think this covers all your bases with a very minimal amount of code.

```
var dynamicApiIds = result.Components
  .SelectMany(c => new[] { c.DynamicApiChoicesId, c.DynamicApiSubmissionsId}) // combine
  .OfType<int>() // remove nulls
  .Distinct();
```

Comment: I would not have expected `OfType` to work like that but this does indeed work correctly.

Comment: very interesting answer, went with Jack's in the end because I think that is a bit more readable. Would be curious to know if this would execute faster, however

Answer (score 0):

To map each element in the source list onto more than one element on the destination list, you can use `SelectMany`.

```
var combined = componentsWithDynamicApis
    .SelectMany(x => new[] { x.DynamicApiChoicesId.Value, x.DynamicApiSubmissionsId.Value })
    .Distinct();
```

Comment: This doesn't handle nulls correctly.

Comment: @JackA. the `componentsWithDynamicApis` already handled that

Comment: although I think this will throw an error. Not every component will have both Choices and Submissions

Comment: That's a problem with the original post, too, Adjit. Is that something you're asking people to help you solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have not tested it but you can use `SelectMany` with filtering out the null values like below :

```
var componentsWithDynamicApis = result
  .Components
.Select(r=> new [] {r.DynamicApiChoicesId,r.DynamicApiSubmissionsId})
.SelectMany(r=> r.Where(p=> p!=null).Cast<int>()).Distinct();
```

Comment: Need to convert to `int`. This leaves the items as `int?`.

Comment: @JackA. added a cast.